# Empty href is not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched the forum for this and I cannot find a solution to my problem. If I missed something please point me to the right thread.

I have three divs that replace each other onclick.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="a">AAAA <a id="showa" href="javascript:void(0)">Show A</a></div>
<div id="b">BBBB <a id="showb" href="javascript:void(0)">Show B</a></div>
<div id="c">CCC <a id="showc" href="javascript:void(0)">Show C</a></div>
```

And I am using this javascript to achieve this:

```
function ReplaceDivs(a,b,c){
    $("#showa").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#b").show();
    $("#a").hide();
    $("#c").hide();
});

$("#showb").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#c").show();
    $("#b").hide();
    $("#a").hide();
});

$("#showc").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#a").show();
    $("#b").hide();
    $("#c").hide();
});
```

I am using `preventDefault` and I also tried entering by entering `javascript:void(0)` but my code is still not working.

It's working without a problem when I am testing it on fiddle.

You can see my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CJ_/k4qyoufo/)

You can see the actual page [here](http://demo.topcircle.topgreekgyms.gr/business/test-2/)

What I am missing?

Also, I was wondering if there's a way to add animation so the divs show/hide nicer. This is the first time I am working on javascript so I don't really know where to start on this.

Comment: Check your browser's console for errors when you load your page.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: I check the file that includes the js code but there are no errors.

Comment: @Anonymous If I leave the "href" empty it tries to load the page. It I point to `javascript:;` or `javascript:void(0)` nothing happens.

Comment: @kat_indo Ah, there is plenty of information on that online.

Comment: @Anonymous I agree. I have spent the last hour trying different solutions, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @kat_indo Out of curiosity, do you ever call the function? You don't in the example.

Comment: @Anonymous It looks like I don't. I am trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Try adding 'return false;' inside all 3 functions at the end of the functions.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have any Javascript errors.  From the code above, it seems to be that you are not properly closing parentheses/brackets.  Check your console for errors.  Usually when there is a Javascript error, your click events won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The code on your actual page is `<a id="showa" href="">Show A</a>`. A blank `href` equals a link to self. You need this:

```
<a href="javascript:;"></a>
```

This is the preferred way for links without an action.

Comment: I see you updated the link on your page so it doesn't fire a page reload. But you still need to implement the jQuery that is modifying the element with `id="showa"`

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I have already added my js code. It's actually placed here: `wp-content/themes/twmp-child-theme/js/dynamicdivs.js`. When I check the file I don't see any errors. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I see. You have the code wrapped in `ReplaceDivs() {`. Is that function called on body load? Because if it's not, then the `.on` event handlers don't get called either.

Comment: I use WordPress so I call the file with a function. When I check my `head` I see that the file is loaded. Also, the top code that I am using works fine, so I think I don't have a problem there.

Comment: Where does the function "ReplaceDivs" get called on your page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73005/discussion-between-kat-indo-and-bytecode77).

Comment: Actually, the preferred way is to have a real link, in case JavaScript is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. The solution in my case was fixing the path to jquery source.

Before

```
<script src="scripts/vendors.js"></script>
```

After

```
<script src="/scripts/vendors.js"></script>
```

Added a slash in the path before scripts/...
I got this problem when I created a new page-> typed in the source path-> picking up the source path. 
But it worked fine without the front slash in other sample prebuild pages that i got as template. Yet to figure out the resaon for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `#` for the value of your `href`.